# Does latex have the z-index property

Tags: backgrounds

May be this is a very strange question. 
But I found this property is very useful to control the overlap element.

So I wonder if latex own this property as HTML div.

Do you have any better idea to solve the overlap problem. Sometime, I need to push some 
element back.

**update**:the MWE code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{calc}

\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\colorbox{gray}{#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,
labelfont=white,
textfont=white,
singlelinecheck=false,
margin=0pt,
font={bf,footnotesize}
}

\newlength\tdima
\setlength\tdima{ \fboxsep+\fboxrule}

\lstset{
         basicstyle=\small\tt,
         tabsize=2,                  
         extendedchars=true,         
         breaklines=true,           
         mathescape,
         escapeinside={\%*}{*)},        
         showspaces=false,          
         showtabs=false,             
         showstringspaces=false,      
         columns=flexible,
         xleftmargin=\tdima,
         framextopmargin= 10pt,
         framexbottommargin=10pt,
         float=tp,                            % float setting
         frame=single,
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=overlap]
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

The caption overlap with the frame. And I want to push the caption back. Let the frame cover it. 
I don't want to use the \vskip to fine tuning the caption position.

Comment: Please give a minimal working example (MWE) where you want to control such an overlapping.

Comment: @canaaerus please take a look at the revised edition question

Comment: I guess adding another `\colorbox` with a white background around the code should be the way to go, although I don't know how to achieve this with `lstlisting`. (As you can see the border is already in front of the label.) Maybe just adding `backgroundcolor=\color{white}` will do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a dimension to `\fboxsep`, as follows:

```
  \DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\fboxsep=1.2pt....
```

[image]

Comment: how do you figure out the 1.2pt

Comment: @pythonee Newton–Raphson's method:) i.e., it looked that much and I tried it out, didn't want to read through the code.

Comment: We usually name it as  "trial and error" method.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. `\fboxsep` is a specific solution to the specific problem that OP had, it doesn't appear to be in any way related to z-index.